# how to change a theme through themekey on the contact page in drupal 7

Tags: theming, emails

I made a site in drupal 7 and used themekey (i'm using "nid" for all the pages) to have on every page a different backgrounds, this works perfect. But on the contact page i'm not able to find the way to do this, what are the settings in themekey to set a different background in the contact page.

Thx
Fred

Answer (score 1):

I think setting `drupal:path` to `contact` should do the trick.